# Raspberry Pi sudo apt-get update not working

Tags: apt, update

I am getting the following message whenever I try to run:
`sudo apt-get update` :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update 
Get:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease [8,084 B]
Err:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease
Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Get:2 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease [8,084 B]
Err:2 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease
Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Fetched 16.2 kB in 0s (113 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch
http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My Pi is currently using Ethernet, not WiFi.

Comment: have you searched the internet for `Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT'` - edit: seems to be a "proxy" issue

Comment: @JaromandaX is likely correct. Your issue is most likely that your ISP is running a faulty proxy. [Read this Q&A for details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474549/got-nodata-issue-nodata-does-the-network-require-authentication)

Comment: Does one of the answers help you? If so it would be nice if you could accept one to finish your question.

Answer (score 23):

I assume you are using **Raspbian**. It could be that your installation lists are broken. I suggest to reinitialize them by editing *sources.list* and *raspi.list*. By default they look like this:

```
rpi ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi

rpi ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
```

In both files comment the first line with a `#` and any additional repository if present. Then do:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
```

This will clear the lists from *apt* in `/var/lib/apt/lists/`. It it nearly then same by doing `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and  `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*` but under control of the packet manager. Then uncomment the lines you have commented and do:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a network connection which provides Internet access via a proxy. If you can browse the web, check your browser settings to see what the proxy is. Otherwise ask someone in charge of the network.

Once you know the proxy name, port and optionally username and password, set it up on your RPi either via `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or using environment variables such as `$http_proxy`. Check out [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/349702/apt-conf-acquirehttpproxy-proxyserverport-seems-not-to-be-used-ubuntu-13) for syntax.