# Neither sudo apt-get upgrade nor sudo apt-get install vim working

Tags: raspbian, apt, sudo

I just started Raspberry pi and was ordered to get vim installed. However whenever I run `sudo apt-get install vim` 
I get the following errors:

> Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf
>   vim-runtime all 2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u1 Connection failed [IP:
>   93.93.128.193 80] E: Failed to fetch
>
> http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/v/vim/vim_8.0.0197-4+deb9u1_armhf.deb
>   Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
>
> E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with
>   --fix-missing?

So this time I run `sudo apt-get update` which works perfectly (unlike Ubuntu, typing sudo isn't asking me password)

Then I do `sudo apt-get upgrade`. which returns 83 errors, I paste here some of them:

> Err:1 http://raspbian.mirror.net.in/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main
>   armhf base-files armhf 9.9+rpi1+deb9u8 403 Forbidden

and

> E: Failed to fetch
>   http://raspbian.mirror.net.in/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/b/base-files/base-files_9.9+rpi1+deb9u8_armhf.deb
>   403 Forbidden

Research from my side tells me that I should do this:

> sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/status
>
> sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/status

but I don't have any /dpkg in my /lib

Solution 2 that didn't work for me:

> edit /etc/apt/sources.list and replace 
>   http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian with a mirror address from 
>   https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors (from the website: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=123260)

because my source.list file looks nothing like mentioned above, so I didn't messed with it.

Comment: Did you intentionally word wrap the text? It is almost unreadable.

Comment: @RalfFriedl sorry, I did. I thought it will make errors more stand out and easy to read. It turned out to be a bad idea. I'm editing it

Comment: Try again there's been some Raspbian mirroring problems this week. You'll also want `vim-full` to get all of the sensible vim options working.

Comment: Thankyou @Dougie. I have been trying for last three hours. Right now, I'll report this error as something at their (raspberry pi)end. I hope it works soon!

Comment: I have same issue and in my case it was caused by application firewall Fortinet which block traffic to repository sites.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your package list files are messed. You can try to reinitialize them. You can do it by deleting the list files but that is the brute force method. I suggest to do it under control of the package manager so it has a chance to notice the changes. How to do it you can look at [Raspberry Pi sudo apt-get update not working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93630/79866).