# Illegal instruction when trying to update package on Raspbian-Lite

Tags: pi-2, apt, raspbian-lite

On Raspbian Lite I'm trying to run apt-get upgrade but running into following issue:

```
Setting up libssl1.0.2:armhf (1.0.2r-1~deb9u1) ...
dpkg: error processing package libssl1.0.2:armhf (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script was killed by signal (Illegal instruction)
```

So I tried reconfiguring but that also fails.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up libssl1.0.2:armhf (1.0.2r-1~deb9u1) ...
dpkg: error processing package libssl1.0.2:armhf (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script was killed by signal (Illegal instruction)
```

I tried running apt-get update, clean, reconfigure in a few combinations but always end up with the same issue. So I started suspecting it's the sources - but they look clean.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

Any suggestion what else to check are welcome. 
This is PI 2B+

Comment: You may want to also check any additional sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/sources.list.5.en.html

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible that your installation list files are broken. This files are downloaded when running `sudo apt update`. They can be found in `/var/lib/apt/lists/*`. You could delete and update them. But it is better to do it under control of the package manager. How to do it you can look at [Raspberry Pi sudo apt-get update not working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93630/79866).

If it doesn't help you can try to reinstall

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt --reinstall install libssl1.0.2
```

and next step more aggressive

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt --reinstall --fix-broken install libssl1.0.2
```

Comment: Tried the solution from the link, than I tried manually removing everything from /var/lib/apt/lists/ and run update & upgrade. Unfortunately I'm getting exactly same error still.

Comment: @jackrobot I have updated the answer.

Comment: I think I have found the problem... the issue is not with libssl but with these packages. Openssh-server could be a problem because it's a headless setup. When I will have more time I need to plug this to monitor and try to reinstall them. Thanks for the suggestions Ingo!
Errors were encountered while processing:
 avahi-daemon
 lighttpd
 openssh-server