# ~ $ sudo apt-get install samba samba-common-bin --------> Spits out dependency error

Tags: software-installation, apt, samba

I'm new to the Raspberry Pi platform and also complitly new to Linux OS. That said, trubleshooting by my self is pretty much impossible. I hope I can find some help here :)

I wanted to install Samba, tho i could open a network folder set up on my Windows machine. To do that, I found these command lines online:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install samba samba-common-bin
```

But no matter what I try after searching for houres in forums, I allways get this error messege:

```
pi@raspberrypi:— $ sudo apt-get install samba samba-common-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
samba : Depends: python-samba but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.2.14+dfsg-O+deb8u11) but 2:4.5.12+dfsg-2+deb9u3 is to be installed
        Depends: samba-dsdb-modules but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.2.14+dfsg-O+deb8u11) but 2:4.5.12+dfsg-2+deb9u3 is to be installed
        Recommends: attr but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: samba-vfs-modules but it is not going to be installed
samba-common-bin : Depends: python-samba but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.2.14+dfsg-O+deb8u11) but 2:4.5.12+dfsg-2+deb9u3 is to be installed
                   Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.2.14+dfsg-O+deb8u11) but 2:4.5.12+dfsg-2+deb9u3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am sorry if this is a dumb question to ask, but I have simply no clue what Im doing wrong... If you need further Information please contact me, I will be fast to give them If I can!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something messed with your package manager. You may try to "reset" it. Just follow this answer to [Raspberry Pi sudo apt-get update not working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93630/79866). Then remove partially installed samba with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt --autoclean purge samba
```

and reboot. Then try to install **samba** again with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install samba
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! That worked perfectly!

Comment: @ValentinStorre Glad to help you ;-) It would be nice if you could accept the answer with a tick on the tick on the left side. This will finish the question and show others that is has a solution.

Comment: Great answer, +1. Just a suggestion for your consideration: Include the steps from the [referenced answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93630/83790) in this answer. I feel a complete answer may be more useful for some.

Comment: @Seamus I have thought about it but I'm improving my old answers from time to time and searching and modifying them on every place is annoying. Something like an *include* tag would be nice ..

Comment: Good point... maybe make that as a feature suggestion? But perhaps there's a more direct approach... do you have a [GitHub](https://github.com/) account?

Comment: @Seamus Yes, I have a GitHub account, but what makes the different?

Comment: I just wondered if you'd considered using github as a sort of repository for your answers. I do something similar with mine. Can you share the location of your site?

Comment: @Seamus https://github.com/ingo-h but not used very extensive.

Comment: OK - will follow up on another channel.