# apt aborts while reading package lists

Tags: apt

When trying to run `sudo apt-get update`, I get three lines of output when all is said and done:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch InRelease
Aborted package lists... 97%
```

Prior to being all said and done, the last line will read:

```
Reading package lists... XX%
```

Where XX is a value that gets larger over a short period of time.

It repeatedly aborts at 97%

I'm running a Rasberry Pi 3B.

What might be going on here?

Comment: How long does it take to get to 97%?  Also check `df | grep mmcblk0` to make sure you are not running out of space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to say what's going wrong with your package lists. I haven't seen this abort before. But always a good attempt to fix issues with package lists is to reinitialize them. How to do it under control of the package manager you can look at [Raspberry Pi sudo apt-get update not working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93630/79866).