# apt-get python error ImportError No module named io

Tags: raspbian, python

I can no longer install or remove any software using apt-get.  When I try I get the error:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
ImportError: No module names 'io'
```

I tried to reinstall python but that just brings up this error again.

I'm running Raspbian.

**Update** from comments:
Here is the error log: https://pastebin.com/nXmRTx03
and `pip install io` gives me: https://pastebin.com/DtHqfc3n

Comment: I'm not super experienced with Linux.  How would I generate an error log for this?

Comment: Also, `No module names 'io'` seems to me a very grievious issue. `io` is a module upon which *many* Python-based programs operate. `pip install io` might resolve it, if pip isn't dependent upon `io`.

Comment: This is unlikely to be related specifically to Raspberry Pi.  It seems like a generic Linux issue that might get better attention elsewhere.

Comment: error log: https://pastebin.com/nXmRTx03

Comment: @Brick Do you know a good place to post this?

Comment: @Brick, this is not a general linux question because not all Linux systems depend on aptitude (`apt`). Aptitude is specific to Debian upon which Raspbian is based.

Comment: To be more precise, a general Debian question then. @user96931  May get better attention, e.g., here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: pip install io gives me: https://pastebin.com/DtHqfc3n

Comment: I still get the same issue after

Comment: Ok, type `pcmanfm /usr/lib/python2.7`. Scroll down, do you see `io.py`? What is there?

Comment: If `io.py` is present, this is a problem with $PYTHONPATH and/or virtualenv. Virtualenv goes beyond the scope of my expertise (as I'm an avid Python buff) and I won't know how to fix that. However, this information should give others valuable information with which to help you.

Comment: io.py is there.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the error log there seems to be a general problem with updates. Before trying anything else with python you should fix your update. You only do an `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Before doing it you should update the packages lists. So first try to do:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
```

and reboot. You should now have an up to date system. Check with:

```
rpi ~$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
```

It should not show any upgradable packages. If this does not help then you can try to reinitialze the packet manager. How to do it you can look at [Raspberry Pi sudo apt-get update not working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93630/79866).

If you have a clean updated system then you can try to use python.

Comment: the "sudo apt update" works but the "sudo apt full-upgrade gives the same error as before.

Comment: as soon as I hit y to continue the error appears.

Comment: @TylerBourne Do you reinitialized the package manager?