# Can't connect to the samba server?

Tags: raspbian, internet, samba, file-server

I am trying to set up a file sharing server on this here raspberry pi. The pi is running on Raspbian. I have it plugged in to my Google Wi-Fi router via Ethernet. SSH and ping are working fine, but when I try to install samba it is unable to connect to the server. I can connect to the Raspbian samba download server fine on my laptop.

Here is the `apt-get` output (note that I have *already* run `sudo apt-get update`):

```bsh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install samba samba-common-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  attr ibverbs-providers libavahi-client3 libboost-atomic1.67.0
  libboost-iostreams1.67.0 libboost-regex1.67.0 libboost-system1.67.0
  libboost-thread1.67.0 libcephfs2 libcups2 libgfapi0 libgfrpc0 libgfxdr0
  libglusterfs0 libgpgme11 libibverbs1 libjansson4 libldb1 libnspr4 libnss3
  libpython2.7 librados2 libtdb1 libtevent0 python-crypto python-dnspython
  python-gpg python-ldb python-samba python-talloc python-tdb samba-common
  samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs samba-vfs-modules tdb-tools
Suggested packages:
  cups-common python-crypto-doc bind9 bind9utils ctdb ldb-tools ntp | chrony
  smbldap-tools ufw winbind heimdal-clients
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  attr ibverbs-providers libavahi-client3 libboost-atomic1.67.0
  libboost-iostreams1.67.0 libboost-regex1.67.0 libboost-system1.67.0
  libboost-thread1.67.0 libcephfs2 libcups2 libgfapi0 libgfrpc0 libgfxdr0
  libglusterfs0 libgpgme11 libibverbs1 libjansson4 libldb1 libnspr4 libnss3
  libpython2.7 librados2 libtdb1 libtevent0 python-crypto python-dnspython
  python-gpg python-ldb python-samba python-talloc python-tdb samba
  samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs
  samba-vfs-modules tdb-tools
0 upgraded, 38 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,978 kB/26.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 101 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf samba-libs armhf 2:4.9.5+dfsg-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf python-samba armhf 2:4.9.5+dfsg-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf samba-common all 2:4.9.5+dfsg-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:4 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf samba-common-bin armhf 2:4.9.5+dfsg-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:5 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf samba armhf 2:4.9.5+dfsg-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:6 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf samba-dsdb-modules armhf 2:4.9.5+dfsg-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:7 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf samba-vfs-modules armhf 2:4.9.5+dfsg-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/samba/samba-libs_4.9.5+dfsg-4_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/samba/python-samba_4.9.5+dfsg-4_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/samba/samba-common_4.9.5+dfsg-4_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/samba/samba-common-bin_4.9.5+dfsg-4_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/samba/samba_4.9.5+dfsg-4_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/samba/samba-dsdb-modules_4.9.5+dfsg-4_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/samba/samba-vfs-modules_4.9.5+dfsg-4_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

My `sources.list` looks like this:

```
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source' 
deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free
```

I uncommented that line and updated still no luck.

**Update** with information from comments:
I can successful `ping raspbian.raspberrypi.org` and also get html data with `curl -L http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian` with one of the first lines `<title>Index of /raspbian</title>`.

Comment: Can you ping `raspbian.raspberrypi.org`?

Comment: yeah that seems to be working fine

Comment: Can you get to site `http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian` in your internet browser?

Comment: I am using raspbian buster lite. I don't believe it comes with an internet browser. should have specified that

Comment: Try this: `curl -L http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian`. You should get raw html and one of the first lines should be `<title>Index of /raspbian</title>`. This ensures that you can connect to the repository.

Comment: Yup. connected just fine. got the html

Comment: I don't believe that you need the source packages. You should comment the last line in `sources.list` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the same thing and this worked for me.

Try running:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

Then install Samba as normal.

I got this from [here](https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/09/raspberrypi-file-share/)

Comment: the `full-upgrade` worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have verified that you can connect to the default Raspbian repository. So it may be possible that your package manager has get confused. First comment the last line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` again. You will not need to use packages of the program sources.

You can try to reinitialize the package list files. How to do it look at [Raspberry Pi sudo apt-get update not working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93630/79866). After that try to install samba again.

Answer (score -1):

Run `sudo apt-get update` first.