# Problem installing bind in Buster

Tags: dns, raspbian-buster, repository

I am trying to install Bind 9 on a PI 4b running Buster. Having done `sudo apt-get update`, I enter: `sudo apt-get install bind9 bind9utils dnsutils`.

The error messages that come back indicate that Bind is not yet in the Raspbian Buster repository. I even tried installing it from the desktop installer, and got the same result.

Comment: `apt policy bind9` on my Pi4 says it's available. Please add the full error message to your question.

Comment: Rpi4 Raspbian 10 buster here.  (1) $ sudo apt-get update has 2 erros and 3 warnings.  (2) $ sudo apt-get install bind9 ... has 6 Err's and 7 E's.  I am not surprised because I already found a couple of other similar problems of software/driver not ready for Rpi4.

Answer (score 3):

I have tested it with a fresh flashed [Raspbian Buster Light](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) on a RPi 4B:

```
$ sudo apt-get install bind9 bind9utils dnsutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dns-root-data libirs161 python3-ply
Suggested packages:
  bind9-doc ufw rblcheck python-ply-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bind9 bind9utils dns-root-data dnsutils libirs161 python3-ply
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,675 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,605 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf libirs161 armhf 1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1 [235 kB]
Get:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf dnsutils armhf 1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1 [361 kB]
Get:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf python3-ply all 3.11-3 [65.1 kB]
Get:4 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf bind9utils armhf 1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1 [422 kB]
Get:5 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf dns-root-data all 2019031302 [5,396 B]
Get:6 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf bind9 armhf 1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1 [587 kB]
Fetched 1,675 kB in 1s (1,964 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
---snip---
```

So you have to look at your setup, first at `/etc/apt/sources.list`, or use a fresh flashed image. You may also try to reinitialze the package lists. How to do it you can look at [Raspberry Pi sudo apt-get update not working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93630/79866).