# Raspberry Pi3 freezes during sudo apt-get upgrade

Tags: vnc, update, raspbian-buster

I recently downloaded buster image (2019-07-10) and it is working fine.  However when I run sudo apt-get upgrade I'm getting and error when it is upgrading realvnc with the following message:

> new realvnc-vnc-server package post-removal script subprocess returned
>   error exit status 1

The pi seems completely frozen mouse and keyboard doesn't work, time not updating.  Best way to proceed and what is causing this error?  Alt+PrintScreen + R E I S U B okay to force shut down?

Comment: (1) Your "recently" downloaded buster should be July10 or later. I once downloaded a buster Jun28 version and found apt-get update/upgrade problem.  Problem disappeared when I used the July10 buster.  (2) If the Rpi freezes, then I don't know what terminal commands to reboot or shutdown.  You might like to add the Rpi 3 hardware reset jumper, or Rpi4 Run/GlobalEnalbe jumpers to do manual shutdown.  This is to avoid Rpi SD card corrupted because of shutting down during a SD card write operation.  Another method is to install a watchdog timer, so that Rpi reboots itself after, say two minutes.

Comment: I used the following commands to install realvnc-vnc-server and found no problems: (1) sudo apt-get update
(2) sudo apt-get upgrade
(3) sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
(4) sudo apt install realvnc-vnc-server
(5) sudo apt autoremove.  (a) I am using Rpi4B buster July10 sd Card 16GB C10.

Comment: I also found your suggestion can reboot: Alt + <print screen> + R E I S U B. (1) How to shut down Rpi when frozen 2017mar08
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=176612#p1126208, (2) Magic SysRq Key Wikipedia  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key

Answer (score 1):

Before doing an upgrade you should update the package lists:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl rebooot
```

If this also does not work then you can try to reinitialize the package lists. How to do it look at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93630/79866.