# Cannot install pandas on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python, python-3

I have been trying to install pandas for a week now. Read pretty much every thread I could find but nothing seems to work. I keep getting a ton of import and dpkg errors every time. Everything is up to date.

I have tried:

**sudo apt-get install python-pandas**

**sudo apt install python3-pandas**

Here is the output I get:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pandas
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-pandas is already the newest version (0.19.2-5.1+rpi1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
44 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python-functools32 (3.2.3.2-3) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-functools32 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-numexpr (2.6.1-4) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-numexpr (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up gconf2 (3.2.6-4) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-gconf-defaults", line 180, in <module>
    read_entries(realname)
  File "/usr/bin/update-gconf-defaults", line 139, in read_entries
    for line in file(filename):
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-support (1.0.15) ...
  File "/usr/sbin/update-python-modules", line 52
    print x
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
dpkg: error processing package python-support (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-py (1.4.32-3) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-py (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-cvxopt (1.1.4-1.5+deb9u1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-cvxopt (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-joblib (0.10.3+git55-g660fe5d-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-joblib (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-tz (2016.7-0.3) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-tz (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnomevfs2-common:
 libgnomevfs2-common depends on gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2); however:
  Package gconf2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgnomevfs2-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pandas:
 python-pandas depends on python-tz; however:
  Package python-tz is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-pandas (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnomevfs2-extra:armhf:
 libgnomevfs2-extra:armhf depends on libgnomevfs2-common (= 1:2.24.4-6.1); however:
  Package libgnomevfs2-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgnomevfs2-extra:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-jdcal (1.0-1.2~deb9u1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-jdcal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-matplotlib:
 python-matplotlib depends on python-tz; however:
  Package python-tz is not configured yet.
 python-matplotlib depends on python-functools32; however:
  Package python-functools32 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-matplotlib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-schedule:
 gnome-schedule depends on python-support (>= 0.90.0); however:
  Package python-support is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-schedule (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pytest:
 python-pytest depends on python-py (>= 1.4.29); however:
  Package python-py is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-pytest (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-cycler (0.10.0-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-cycler (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-dateutil (2.5.3-2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-dateutil (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-gobject-2 (2.28.6-13) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-gobject-2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-imaging (4.0.0-4) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-imaging (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-openpyxl:
 python-openpyxl depends on python-jdcal; however:
  Package python-jdcal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-openpyxl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-xlrd (1.0.0-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-xlrd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-bs4 (4.5.3-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-bs4 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-lxml (3.7.1-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-lxml (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-cairo (1.8.8-2.2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-cairo (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-decorator (4.0.11-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-decorator (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-antlr (2.7.7+dfsg-7) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-antlr (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-tables:
 python-tables depends on python-numexpr; however:
  Package python-numexpr is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-tables (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-subprocess32 (3.2.7-2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-subprocess32 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-nose (1.3.7-2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-nose (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-patsy (0.4.1+git34-ga5b54c2-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-patsy (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-webencodings (0.5-2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-webencodings (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-pyparsing (2.1.10+dfsg1-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-pyparsing (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-gconf:
 python-gconf depends on python-gobject-2 (>= 2.17.0); however:
  Package python-gobject-2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-gconf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnomevfs2-0:armhf:
 libgnomevfs2-0:armhf depends on libgnomevfs2-common (= 1:2.24.4-6.1); however:
  Package libgnomevfs2-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgnomevfs2-0:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnomeui-0:armhf:
 libgnomeui-0:armhf depends on libgnomevfs2-0 (>= 1:2.17.90); however:
  Package libgnomevfs2-0:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgnomeui-0:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-scipy:
 python-scipy depends on python-decorator; however:
  Package python-decorator is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-scipy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-gnome2:
 python-gnome2 depends on libgnomeui-0 (>= 2.22.0); however:
  Package libgnomeui-0:armhf is not configured yet.
 python-gnome2 depends on libgnomevfs2-0 (>= 1:2.17.90); however:
  Package libgnomevfs2-0:armhf is not configured yet.
 python-gnome2 depends on python-gconf (= 2.28.1+dfsg-1.2); however:
  Package python-gconf is not configured yet.
 python-gnome2 depends on python-gobject-2 (>= 2.17.0); however:
  Package python-gobject-2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-gnome2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-xlwt:
 python-xlwt depends on python-antlr; however:
  Package python-antlr is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-xlwt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-gtk2:
 python-gtk2 depends on python-cairo (>= 1.0.2-1.1); however:
  Package python-cairo is not configured yet.
 python-gtk2 depends on python-gobject-2 (>= 2.21.3); however:
  Package python-gobject-2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-gtk2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnome-2-0:armhf:
 libgnome-2-0:armhf depends on libgnomevfs2-0 (>= 1:2.17.90); however:
  Package libgnomevfs2-0:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgnome-2-0:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-glade2:
 python-glade2 depends on python-gtk2 (= 2.24.0-5.1); however:
  Package python-gtk2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-glade2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-statsmodels:
 python-statsmodels depends on python-scipy; however:
  Package python-scipy is not configured yet.
 python-statsmodels depends on python-patsy; however:
  Package python-patsy is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-statsmodels (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-html5lib:
 python-html5lib depends on python-webencodings; however:
  Package python-webencodings is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-html5lib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libbonoboui2-0:armhf:
 libbonoboui2-0:armhf depends on libgnome-2-0; however:
  Package libgnome-2-0:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libbonoboui2-0:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-functools32
 python-numexpr
 gconf2
 python-support
 python-py
 python-cvxopt
 python-joblib
 python-tz
 libgnomevfs2-common
 python-pandas
 libgnomevfs2-extra:armhf
 python-jdcal
 python-matplotlib
 gnome-schedule
 python-pytest
 python-cycler
 python-dateutil
 python-gobject-2
 python-imaging
 python-openpyxl
 python-xlrd
 python-bs4
 python-lxml
 python-cairo
 python-decorator
 python-antlr
 python-tables
 python-subprocess32
 python-nose
 python-patsy
 python-webencodings
 python-pyparsing
 python-gconf
 libgnomevfs2-0:armhf
 libgnomeui-0:armhf
 python-scipy
 python-gnome2
 python-xlwt
 python-gtk2
 libgnome-2-0:armhf
 python-glade2
 python-statsmodels
 python-html5lib
 libbonoboui2-0:armhf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am really not sure what is happening here. I was able to install pandas on other systems 100's of times within a few seconds.

Comment: I just did `sudo apt install python-pandas python3-pandas` and it worked okay.  Took about 5 minutes though.  I suspect you have screwed up your packages by trying to install by non-standard means.

Comment: @user3088202, Ah, let me see.  To get rid of dpkg errors, I usually use GUI Rpi Desktop > Preferences > Search to install.  Just now I searched "pandas" with more than 20 results, some related to things I don't know, such as neuroscience and databases.  I picked a couple of packages which I think are basic and installed without any problem.  Of course I might later found dependency problems.  My quick and dirty prototyping is install more and more dependent packages until no more dpkg errors coming up.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that your package lists are broken. Because you don't mention you have done it, it is always a good idea to

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl reboot
```

If it doesn't help you may try to reinitialize your package lists. How to do it you can look at [Raspberry Pi sudo apt-get update not working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93630/79866).