# My apt is broken (Illegal instruction)

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, apt

When I run `apt update`, or any other apt, Im getting an error saying "illegal instruction", just like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt update
Illegal instruction
```

no other errormessages given.
I followed [this guide](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93630/107269) but that did not help.

I have previously been trying to install Debian (armhf) packages by `dpkg -i`. Might that have destroyed something?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `apt` or one of the shared library it uses is broken. `apt` depends on `apt-get` so you can try:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt-get update
```

If it doesn't work then you can try to download the **apt** package and install it again with `dpkg` in the hope it will repair the broken programs. **But first make a backup from your SD Card and check if you can restore it!**

```
# download for stretch
rpi ~$ wget http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.4.9_armhf.deb

# download for buster
rpi ~$ wget http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.8.2_armhf.deb
```

But before installing **apt**, first deinstall all packages from debian:

```
rpi ~$ sudo dpkg --purge debian-package1-armhf   # and others
# ...
rpi ~$ sudo dpkg --install apt_1.4.9_armhf.deb   # for stretch
# or
rpi ~$ sudo dpkg --install apt_1.8.2_armhf.deb   # for buster
```

Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are absolutely sure of what you are doing don't mix Raspbian and Debian packages (or use any other repository other than Raspbian).

Debian for ARM uses a different ARM architecture (or it used to).  It is targeted at more modern variants of the processor comapared to the rather old chips used in the Pi.

Comment: Thats what I have learned today. But how do I fix my problem? I would want to avoid to reinstall the whole system.

Comment: I suppose you would have to reinstall from Raspbian all those packages you installed from Debian.  Possible simplest, certainly safest, to do a complete reinstall.