# Campus Network wi-fi issue

Tags: raspbian, networking, apt

I have a raspberry pi which is connected to University network via wi-fi. I usually just ssh to it through my PC if i want to do anything. The internet is working as I can ping google and even fetch data from the internet using basic commands. However, when I try to perform apt-get update, the following error pops-up

[image: error message]

My understanding is that there is some sort of required authentication that I do not know about. It works fine at home if anything. My question is if there's anything that can be done to get rid of this error?? Please help

Comment: Hello and welcome – Please avoid adding the picture of commands. Check [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=17016&start=25#p1040081) out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raspberry Pi sudo apt-get update not working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93604/raspberry-pi-sudo-apt-get-update-not-working)

Comment: none of this worked, thanks for your help though. I might just update it next time I'm back home