# I've got same error while trying to install anything using `sudo apt-get`

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, apt, packages, dpkg

Everytime I want to install anything using `sudo apt-get` command I get this error:

> dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libargon2-1:armhf'
> missing; assuming package has no files currently installed dpkg:
> warning: files list file for package 'libaribb24-0:armhf' missing;
> assuming package has no files currently installed dpkg: unrecoverable
> fatal error, aborting:  files list file for package 'bind9-host'
> contains empty filename E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error
> code (2)

How to get rid of this?

`dpkg -a --configure` does not work

Comment: Do you meant `apt-get`? Or are you really leaving out the hyphen?

Comment: Sorry, it's `apt-get`

Comment: try to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: @kyjanond  As I've written in the post, `dpkg --configure -a` does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that there is a problem with the **files list**. The files list is updated with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
```

so this is the first you should do. And afterwards it is always a good idea to upgrade your installed software with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
```

If this does not help you can try to completely [reinitialize the files list](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93630/79866).

Comment: Doesn't work. The second option "reinitialising the files list" doesn't work either.

Comment: @Cimlah Seems it's a problem with `dpkg` itself. You may check with the debug option. Get help with `dpkg --debug=help`.

Comment: Could you please expand your statement? I don't quite know how to solve the problem with just information given of using `dpkg --debug=help`