# When I try and update pihole I get dpkg: error: parsing file

Tags: pi-zero-w

This is the error I get:

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 1740 package 'firmware-brcm80211':
 duplicate value for 'Status' field
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I don't really know what I am doing so any advice helps!

Edit:
When I run sudo apt dist-upgrade -y I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  rpi-eeprom-images
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libfl2 pciutils rpi.gpio-common
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apt apt-transport-https apt-utils base-files bind9-host binutils binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf
  binutils-common bluez bluez-firmware ca-certificates curl distro-info-data dnsutils
  dphys-swapfile e2fsprogs firmware-atheros firmware-brcm80211 firmware-misc-nonfree
  firmware-realtek git git-man idn2 iputils-ping libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0 libbind9-161
  libbinutils libcom-err2 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libdns-export1104 libdns1104 libext2fs2
  libgnutls30 libicu63 libidn2-0 libirs161 libisc-export1100 libisc1100 libisccc161 libisccfg163
  libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common liblwres161 libpam-chksshpwd libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin
  libpam-runtime libpam-systemd libpam0g libpython3.7 libpython3.7-minimal libpython3.7-stdlib
  libraspberrypi-bin libraspberrypi-dev libraspberrypi-doc libraspberrypi0 libss2 libssl1.1
  libsystemd0 libudev1 openssh-client openssh-server openssh-sftp-server openssl php7.3-cgi
  php7.3-cli php7.3-common php7.3-json php7.3-opcache php7.3-readline php7.3-sqlite3
  pi-bluetooth python-apt-common python-rpi.gpio python3-apt python3.7 python3.7-minimal
  raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel raspberrypi-sys-mods raspi-config rpi-eeprom
  rpi-eeprom-images rpi-update ssh sudo systemd systemd-sysv tzdata udev wpasupplicant
93 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/172 MB of archives.
After this operation, 8,833 kB of additional disk space will be used.
apt-listchanges: Reading changelogs...
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 1740 package 'firmware-brcm80211':
 duplicate value for 'Status' field
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: Did run run the update as Pi?  Did you put `sudo` at the front of the command? What version are you currently on?

Comment: Run `sudo apt update;sudo apt dist-upgrade -y` and add the full output to your question if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is something broken with your package lists. You can try to reinitialize it. You can direct delete the files containing the package lists and then `update` and `full-upgrade` it again. But I think it is better to do it under control of the package manager. How to do look at [Raspberry Pi sudo apt-get update not working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93630/79866).

Comment: I followed the steps in that link and I am still getting the same error as in the original post.