# upgrad tzdata encountered error

Tags: update

After completeing sudo apt update, I had problems with apt upgrade which encountered the following error:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  tzdata
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/266 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Reading changelogs... Done
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 47674 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../tzdata_2020e-0+deb10u1_all.deb ...
Unpacking tzdata (2020e-0+deb10u1) over (2020d-0+deb10u1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/tzdata_2020e-0+deb10u1_all.deb (--unpack):
 error creating symbolic link './usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Chile/Continental': Structure needs cleaning
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/tzdata_2020e-0+deb10u1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have searched around for something similar but not found one. Not that familiar with linux... Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your apt cache for the downloaded packages is broken. You can try to reinitialize it. How to do it look at [Raspberry Pi sudo apt-get update not working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93630/79866).