# Getting error that say "you must fix your apt package-management system" when trying to install Pi-Apps

Tags: pi-apps

I just got a Raspberry Pi 4 B and I'm using Linux on it for the first time ever so excuse me if I say something stupid here. I tried downloading Pi-Apps using the `wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Botspot/pi-apps/master/install | bash` command and I got the error code `The command 'sudo apt update' failed. Before Pi-Apps will work, you must fix your apt package-management system.` I tried rebooting the system and trying the command again. I tried [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93630/156849) fix, but for some reason I was denied permission to the sources.list file and I couldn't save it, even after making myself the root user.
Edit: I'm using Raspbian, "11 (bullseye)".

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo apt update;sudo apt dist-upgrade -y`?

Comment: @Dougie  I get the response `The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfuse2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded`. I tried running `wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Botspot/pi-apps/master/install | bash` again and got the same error,

Comment: @Milliways I'm using Raspbian. I will edit this into my post.

Comment: @jsotola. Noted. Edited the title.

Comment: *"It covers dozens of different OS spanning 10 years."* -> Is extremely misleading unless you would also consider Windows 9 a different OS than Windows 10 and MacOS X 10 a different OS than MacOS X 10.5, which would be difficult to justify unless your definition of "different OS" included making a few configuration changes and adding a few bits of software (in which case everyone is probably running "a different OS" than anyone else).  Following that logic, we might as well consider Chrome v.117 and Chrome v.109 "different web browsers" and so on and so forth.

Comment: **Conventionally, however,** macOS is considered **the same OS** as OSX and, likewise, RpiOS (or whatever you want to call it) is **the same OS** as Raspbian, which, like OSX, had its name changed from one version to another.  So, @Darciukas, the actual question is *"Which version of the Raspberry Pi OS are you using?"* the answer to which you will find via `cat /etc/os-release` in the `VERSION` field (interestingly, this file still refers to the OS by its original name, Debian GNU/Linux, which is essentially what it is).

Comment: @miliways okay, the version is "11 (bullseye)". Also thank you goldilocks for the in-depth answer and correction.

Comment: You appear to have the latest *Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye*. I suggest you first update to latest software; either use the update icon on the toolbar (a circle with a down arrow) OR at the command line `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt full-upgrade -y`. NOTE the package you are trying to install requires Raspberry Pi OS with Desktop.

Comment: @Milliways tried both commands, still doesn't work sadly. Also, I assume I am on Raspberry Pi OS with Desktop because I'm using it like I would a normal computer. I have a monitor, a keyboard and a mouse connected. In fact I'm even typing this message from the Raspberry Pi

Comment: Sorry I can't suggest anything else. It appears to be a problem with what you are trying to install. Frankly I wouldn't touch that app and it is unclear why you are trying to use it. Most people manage to install what they need though the repository. What do you want to do with your Pi?

Comment: Thank you for everyone's help in this thread, but I recently reinstalled Linux on my Pi because of an unrelated issue, and now I can install Pi-Apps without a problem. Sorry if anyone in the future is coming across this post with hopes for an answer.